# Probability of extracting two numbers $a,b$ from $n$ numbers such that $|a − b|$ is $1$

Tags: probability

This problem is from the first sheet of homework exercises from an Introductory Probability Course. We extract $2$ numbers $a,b$ from a box containing $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$. We have to calculate the probability of getting $|a − b|$ equal to $1$ with and without reentry of the balls.

My approach is simple and clearly wrong. Without reentry I took $P[B_{[ok]}] = 1÷[n−1]$ if a is 1 or n and $P[B_{[ok]}] = 2÷[n−1]$ otherwise. With re-entry I took  $P[B_{[ok]}] = 1÷n$ if a is 1 or n and $P[B_{[ok]}] = 2÷n$ otherwise.

The question is what is the problem in this approach?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable, you just need to combine the two results to get one result.

Comment: $$P(a=1\lor a=n)\cdot\frac1{n-1}+P(2\leq a\leq n-1)\cdot \frac2{n-1}$$

Comment: The other way is to consider all pairs $(a,b)$ (with $a\neq b$ if we are in the without replacement case.) There are $n^2$ pairs with replacement and $n^2-n$ without. Of those pairs, there are $2(n-1)$ pairs with $|a-b|=1.$ So ou get $\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2}$ with replacement and $\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2-n}=\frac2{n}$ without.

Comment: This actually lets you compute the probability that $|a-b|=k,$ for $k=1,\dots,n-1$ as $$\frac{2(n-k)}{n^2}\text{ or }\frac{2(n-k)}{n(n-1)}$$